# Command 'java' not found on WSL, even though 'java' command works in Powershell

Tags: java, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jdk

This topic probably is a common one, but when looking online I didn't see much that related to my case, since I'm not running a normal ubuntu, but rather WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

So my problem is that I switched from java 8 to java 17 recently (I required java 8 for a course), but I noticed that on ubuntu terminals, `java -version` still showed `openjdk-1.8.(something)`, rather than `jdk-17` or something like that.

So I thought that uninstalling openjdk would do the trick, which I did with `sudo apt-get autoremove openjdk-8-jre`. However, now typing `java` in an ubuntu terminal doesn't work anymore at all, and shows: `Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with: ...`. But I fear that installing it with one of these commands will install a new version of java, rather than using the one that's already installed.

I have set the `JAVA_HOME` variable to the java installation directory, which is `mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.1`, but the space in Program Files does seem to be a problem.

How can I fix this? I usually prefer using a bash terminal than Powershell or cmd because I know the commands better, so not being able to use `java` or `javac` in bash is an issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few... unique things about WSL that matter here. First, if you type the name of a `.exe` that is in the Windows side, but from WSL, it will work. For example, open a Bash prompt in WSL, type `notepad.exe`, and press enter. Notepad will open.

Before you uninstalled OpenJDK 8, you had `openjdk-8-jre` installed in WSL *and* Java 17 installed in Windows. When you called `java` from Windows, it was smart enough to add the `.exe`, and run the Windows copy of Java. But, when you switched to WSL, when you typed `java`, it ran the Linux version. But if you typed (into WSL) `java.exe`, it would have launched the Windows version of Java from WSL for the same reason that Notepad worked.

If I wanted to do Java development from WSL, I would uninstall the Windows version of Java completely, install my desired version of Java in WSL (`sudo apt update && sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre`), and just do development from in WSL via the WSL Java compiler.

Comment: That's interesting! I tried `java.exe` and `javac.exe` in the bash terminal and it does work properly! Is it "bad" to do this (i.e. should I uninstall windows java and do sudo apt install), or is it fine but just less intuitive/easy?

Comment: I would uninstall Windows java and just `sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk`. If you are going to develop in Linux, it's better to use the Linux version of Java. Technically, calling the Windows compiler from WSL will work in theory, but it might create unexpected problems like line endings, so I would just uninstall Windows Java and just install the JDK in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `java.exe` instead of `java` in WSL. I provided the commands so that you can

1. create a new java file (using `nano <class_name>.java`)
2. compile it (`javac.exe <class_name>.java`)
3. run and see the output (`java.exe <class_name>`)

I ran the following commands:

```bash
cd /mnt/c/users/adity/desktop 
nano Basic.java
javac.exe Basic.java
java.exe Basic
```

The code in the `Basic.java` file:

```java
public class Basic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Here's the screenshot of the terminal:
[image: Screenshot of the Ubuntu terminal with the commands to create Basic.java, compile and run it.]